# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at localhost:8733 \\\\ What's going on?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I've been trying to follow this python tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zrx8FSEo9lk It's about executing python selenium scripts on an already opened browser.
So far, I have this code: (I was at the 7:12 mark of the video if that helps)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

opt=Options()
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress","localhost:8733")
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\User\Documents\driver for seleniu\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=opt)
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
```

The code didn't work and I got two deprecation warnings, so I changed my code to this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
opt=Options()
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress","localhost:8989")
s=Service(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\driver for seleniu\chromedriver.exe')
driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=s,options=opt)


driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
```

After about 40 seconds or so, the program ends and I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\project1\kok.py", line 7, in <module>
    driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=s,options=opt)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\project1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\project1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 93, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\project1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 268, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\project1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 359, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\project1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\project1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at localhost:8989
from chrome not reachable
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00EB6903+2517251]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E4F8E1+2095329]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D52710+1058576]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D475CE+1013198]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D7056E+1181038]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D6A3FB+1156091]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D6A1E1+1155553]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D9AAAF+1354415]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D9A71A+1353498]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D9639B+1336219]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D727A7+1189799]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D73609+1193481]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01045904+1577972]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x010F0B97+2279047]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00F46D09+534521]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00F45DB9+530601]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E54FF9+2117625]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E598A8+2136232]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E599E2+2136546]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E63541+2176321]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76E0FA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x779D7A9E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x779D7A6E+238]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

So far, I've seen a few posts on situations similar to what's happening right now, but not quite what I'm dealing with. I don't know what to do, or even what's going on. I tried changing the port a few times, but that didn't change anything. Can someone help me??

Also, I'm relatively new to this, so take it easy on me lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I also got this error before, just changed few codes.

```py
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir=C:\Users\amber\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')
options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:8989")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=options)
```

First make sure you cd to your Chrome application, then start it accordingly:

```bash
cd C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application
chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=8989 --user-data-dir="C:\amber\chromeprofile"
```